# AWS Lambda - Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run my script on my local machine using this command `sam local invoke MyFunction` but I got this error message.

```
Invoking main.lambda_handler (python3.8)
Skip pulling image and use local one: amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-python3.8:rapid-1.22.0.
START RequestId: 56f2ad8a-ff9b-49cb-87f0-fda8723627ac Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last): Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'psycopg2'
END RequestId: 56f2ad8a-ff9b-49cb-87f0-fda8723627ac
REPORT RequestId: 56f2ad8a-ff9b-49cb-87f0-fda8723627ac  Init Duration: 0.23 ms Duration: 91.34 ms                                                   Billed Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 128 MB        
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'psycopg2'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

I already cpied and put the library into the AWS Lambda project folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the psycopg2 library in Lambda project folder under `.aws-sam/build` directory.

Although, the best way would be to provide `requirements.txt` file in your lambda project folder and mention your dependencies in there. Then the `sam build` command will download and copy the dependencies in `.aws-sam/build` directory for you.

Without the entry in requirements.txt file, you will loose manually copied files uder  `.aws-sam/build` directory on running subsequent `sam build` command.